# use time column of database table to generate start and end times

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following problem: I have a network with vertices and edges, on which vehicles are moving around. Everytime a vehicle reaches a vertex, the current timestamp along with the vertex and vehicle id is logged into a database. I would need a table with the time difference that vehicles need between two vertces.

Note: The entries are logged ascending with the timestamp, but not necessarily the car_ids nor crossing_ids.

Example:

```
|  ID  | Car_id  | Crossing_id  |     TIMESTAMP       |
|   1  |    1    |      1       | 2010-09-25 05:20:00 |
|   2  |    1    |      2       | 2010-09-25 05:23:00 |
|   3  |    2    |      1       | 2010-09-25 05:25:00 |
|   4  |    1    |      3       | 2010-09-25 05:35:00 |
|   5  |    2    |      5       | 2010-09-25 05:42:00 |
```

Wanted result:

```
| Car_id  | Crossing_id_start |   Timestamp_start   | Crossing_id_end |    Timestamp_end    |
|   1     |         1         | 2010-09-25 05:20:00 |         2       | 2010-09-25 05:23:00 |
|   1     |         2         | 2010-09-25 05:23:00 |         3       | 2010-09-25 05:35:00 |
|   2     |         1         | 2010-09-25 05:25:00 |         5       | 2010-09-25 05:35:00 |
```

Example test data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "test";
CREATE TABLE "test" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "car_id" TEXT NOT NULL , "crossing_id" TEXT NOT NULL , "time" DATETIME);
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(1,'car_1','crossing_1','2010-09-25 05:20:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(2,'car_1','crossing_2','2010-09-25 05:23:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(3,'car_2','crossing_1','2010-09-25 05:25:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(4,'car_1','crossing_3','2010-09-25 05:35:00');
INSERT INTO "test" VALUES(5,'car_2','crossing_5','2010-09-25 05:42:00');
```

Any help is greatly appreciated; most preferred would be sqlite, but any hint on other sql databases is welcome as well!

Thanks in advance,
Sugi

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the exact sqlite syntax but I would approach this in two steps...

1. Put the data into a cursor or temporary table in the order you need it

   `SELECT Car_id, Crossing_id, TIMESTAMP FROM Example ORDER BY Car_id ASC, Crossing_id ASC`
2. Iterate over the rows filling in crossing_id_start and crossing_id_end in the new table where crossing_id_start becomes crossing_id_end as long as the car_id of the current record is the same as the previous record.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, if you know the numbers will be sequential

```
select 
  t1.ID as Car_id, 
  t1.Crossing_id as Crossing_id_start, 
  t1.TIMESTAMP as Timestamp_start, 
  t2.Crossing_id as Crossing_id_end, 
  t2.TIMESTAMP as Timestamp_end
from table t1
join table t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.Crossing_id = t2.Crossing_id + 1
order by Crossing_id_start, Crossing_id_end
```